# Nginx cors enable for html files not working

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, nginx, cors, amazon-cloudfront

I'm setting up magento 2 environment using AWS and CloudFront and trying to enable CORS for static files using nginx config and got it to work for all extensions needed except ".html" files!

Tried to add the header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" globally but still not working for ".html" explicitly

Here is the location directive in my nginx.conf file

```
location /static/ {
    # Uncomment the following line in production mode
    expires max;

    # Remove signature of the static files that is used to overcome the browser cache
    location ~ ^/static/version {
        rewrite ^/static/(version[^/]+/)?(.*)$ /static/$2 last;
    }

    location ~* \.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg|js|css|swf|eot|ttf|otf|woff|woff2|json|html)$ {
        #add_header Cache-Control "public";
        #add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        add_header Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public";
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, OPTIONS';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' '604800';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Host, Content-Type, Origin, Accept';
        expires +1y;

        if (!-f $request_filename) {
            rewrite ^/static/?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$1 last;
        }
    }

    location ~* \.(html)$ {
            add_header Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public";
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, OPTIONS';
    }

    location ~* \.(zip|gz|gzip|bz2|csv|xml)$ {
        add_header Cache-Control "no-store";
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        expires    off;

        if (!-f $request_filename) {
           rewrite ^/static/?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$1 last;
        }
    }
    if (!-f $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^/static/?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$1 last;
    }
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
}
```

It's working for all extensions mentioned like jpg, png ... etc.
But still not working for only ".html" files